Conditional image source for a react project
I am practicing React JS lately, I am fetching cast data from TMDB for the project and using the profile_path data for image source. What my problem is now since some of the cast has null as their profile_path, I could not figure out how to display that.  I know Java very well but I am new to JavaScript.
I tried a person.jpeg i found on the internet to display if it is null but either my condition is wrong or i could not use the image on my folder. So it keeps displaying a broken image icon on my screen for null paths.
import imageSrc from "../assets/person.jpeg";

<Flex mt={"5"} mb={"10"} overflow={"scroll"} gap={"5"}>
      {cast?.length === 0 && <Text> No cast found</Text>}

      {cast &&
        cast?.map((item) => (
          <Box key={item?.id} minW={"150px"}>
            {cast?.profile_path === null && <Image src={imageSrc} />}
            <Image src={`${imagePath}/${item?.profile_path}`} />
            <Text>{item?.name}</Text>
            <Text fontSize={"smaller"} color={"gray.400"}>
              {item?.character}
            </Text>
          </Box>
        ))}
    </Flex>


If you want to have images on React, you can put them in your public/ folder, and then access them this way:
if you have "image.png" in your public/ folder, you may access it like this :
<img src="./image.png" alt="" />

in other way you may import your image at the top of your code as usual:
import logo from './logo.png';
// Your code ...
<img src={logo} alt="Logo" />

